# merging two pdf files into one using node.js on server

Tags: node.js, pdf, merge, server

What is the best way to merge more than one pdf file into one located on server using node.js? Does there exists a npm package to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at any of the packages on npm? I did a quick search for "pdf merge npm" and immediately found 4 results

Comment: A quick search of the internet would have yielded [`pdf-merge`](https://npmjs.com/package/pdf-merge), I use this package as well, the downside of it is needing to install pdftk-server.

Comment: is it possible to install pdftk-server on server.

Comment: @M.Dagiya Of course it is, read the docs for pdf-merge

Answer (score 0):

There's a company claiming to have built a javascript version of iText. iText is a library (exists both in Java and C#) that handles all kinds of pdf operations, generation, and content extraction.

Have a look at http://www.leaningtech.com/cheerpj/demos/